# Adam and Eve and children: Were they practising incest?

Tags: adam-and-eve, children

How did the children of Adam and Eve breed? Was it incest?

By the way, as far as I know the only problem for a brother and a sister to have a child is mutations in DNA.
If Adam and Eve had an original DNA without mutations then their children could make healthy grandchildren.

Comment: FYI, Christianity.SE has tackled this same issue [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/did-adam-and-eves-progeny-commit-incest)

Comment: Exactly! Very interesting! But they do not give a clear answer. Just 4 versions.

Comment: Hi Max!  Sorry - I don't understand your confusion.  The answers there are various theories about how to handle the "Was Adam committing incest."  In Christian theology (and I don't know the Islamic take, hence this is a comment and not a question) the answer is most likely, "Yes, Adam probably did commit incest - but he wasn't breaking a commandment in doing so."  Alternatives (like the Nephilim) are also presented.

Comment: It would be good to know Islamic version on this.

Comment: @AffableGeek of course, Christianity usually has to address this *twice* - once for Adam, once for Noah. Islam has a [far less devastating version of the flood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_view_of_Noah#Differences_from_Judeo-Christian_teachings), so does not get this issue *quite* as much with Nūḥ.

Comment: @MarcGravell Islam has exactly same description of the floods. Quran also says the Ark landed on the mountain in the Mesopotamia. Muslim usually are quite about it so you do not hear it.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter curse you wikipedia! ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell did not get it :(

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter I mean: see the wikipedia article I linked to, which says the opposite

Comment: possible duplicate of [Islam supports the marriage between siblings?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1341/islam-supports-the-marriage-between-siblings)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there is no separate Islamic 'take' on this matter. There would only be one possible theory for this highly controversial question,

It was incest back then according to today's definition of incest.

There is nothing wrong in accepting the fact that God ordered Prophet Adam (pbuh) to marry his sons with his daughters. ([Stories of the Prophets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qisas_Al-Anbiya))

It was in the very beginning of the mankind when God ordered so, so that mankind will expand through its natural system of reproduction.

But, later when there started ego and jealousy, God devised rulings accordingly and banned incest.

Please note that, God always wishes the welfare of the mankind and [he revises/abrogates his previous rulings](http://quran.com/2/106) as and when deemed necessary.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 0):

I heard this lesson long ago from a series called *The stories of the prophets*.

---

> How did the children of Adam and Eve breed? Was it incest?

Adam and Eve had their own set of rules (arabic: *Sharia*) specific to their circumstance.

Eve gave birth to twins everytime she was pregnant, one son and one daughter.

And the ruling was that each pair that was born together was not allowed to get married.

> By the way, as far as I know the only problem for a brother and a sister > to have a child is mutations in DNA.
>   If Adam and Eve had original DNA without mutations
>   then their children could make healthy grandchildren.

I don't think that is right. Biology is more complicated than that I think.

---

I personally think, although interesting to know, it doesn't really matter. It is speculation at the end of the day.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I heard that from Tareq Swaidan in a series he gave. I don't have references.